# French time format - date and hour

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, date

I need to adapt appointment date & hour US format to the french time format in Marketing Cloud.
I have this code but nothing display in the email :

```
%%[ VAR @firstname SET @firstname = AttributeValue("FirstName") ]%%
%%=Uppercase(@firstname)=%%,

%%[VAR @startDate SET @startDate = AttributeValue("Startdatetime")]%% 
Nous vous confirmons votre rendez-vous le %%=FormatDate(@startDate, "DD/MM/YYYY", "à hh:mm", "fr-FR")=%% au magasin %%Magasin_name%%
```

Can someone provide me some help?

I have the following example value in the field

> StartDateTime : 1/7/2021 10:30:00 AM

Thanks in advance

Comment: I ran your code through a test in my BU and it worked fine. Have you verified you set `@StartDateTime` prior to the FormatDate() Function. In your sample above, it is not set and therefore would output null.

Comment: No i do not think it has been done. In fact it was a developer that made it during the past. Can you guide me about the adaptation I have to do ?

Comment: You would set it similar to what you did with `@firstname `

Comment: Ok I made the change and it is displaying (I update my post with the good code. But I still have the us hour displaying and not the French hour. How can I adjust ?

Comment: Are you talking you want to adjust timezones of the time stored in the Attribute?

Comment: Yes I want to get the french timezone :) for now I have the US timezone with this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am moving the info from comments into answer for easier reference and understanding:

**1. Formatted Date was not showing up inside of Email.**

The issue was that the `@StartDateTime` variable was not being set prior to the FormatDate(), meaning it was formatting a null value. Solved like this:

```
%%[ VAR @firstname SET @firstname = AttributeValue("FirstName") ]%%
%%=Uppercase(@firstname)=%%,

%%[VAR @startDate SET @startDate = AttributeValue("Startdatetime")]%% 
Nous vous confirmons votre rendez-vous le %%=FormatDate(@startDate, "DD/MM/YYYY", "à hh:mm", "fr-FR")=%% au magasin %%Magasin_name%%
```

**2. The time/date was following the server time zone (CST - no Daylight savings) instead of the local french time.**

To get around this, I would do a DateAdd() onto your StartDateTime prior to format to push it to the correct time and date for the local region(6 hour difference).  Something like:

```
%%[ VAR @firstname SET @firstname = AttributeValue("FirstName") ]%%
%%=Uppercase(@firstname)=%%,

%%[VAR @startDate SET @startDate = DateAdd(AttributeValue("Startdatetime"),6,'H')]%% 
Nous vous confirmons votre rendez-vous le %%=FormatDate(@startDate, "DD/MM/YYYY", "à hh:mm", "fr-FR")=%% au magasin %%Magasin_name%%
```

Comment: It is working now, I just made a parenthesis correction. Thanks a lot for your precious help :)) I appreciate a lot

Comment: Updated parentheses error inmy answer too and awesome to hear it worked!